# Selecting rows with a given dtype from a mixed-dtype Series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Series from an Excel spreadsheet that's mostly floats, but has some strings that weren't parsed because the currency was in a different locale:

```
s = pd.Series(['1,23', '4.56,78', 1, 2.0, np.nan])
```

I'd like to select just those items that are strings so I can apply conversion:

```
s[s.apply(type) == str] = s[s.apply(type) == str].str.replace('.', '').str.replace(',', '.')
s.astype(float)

0      1.23
1    456.78
2      1.00
3      2.00
4       NaN
dtype: float64
```

But I can't find a good (builtin, vectorized) way to get or select dtypes row-wise.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `str.translate` to do both things at the same time (convert, change the dtype):

```
pd.to_numeric(s.str.translate(str.maketrans({'.': '', ',': '.'}))).fillna(s)

0      1.23
1    456.78
2      1.00
3      2.00
4       NaN
dtype: float64
```

The `dtype` will be `'float64'`.

Comment: OK, that's a pretty good trick for operating on string values.  Is it documented anywhere that most `.str` functions return NaN for non-string values?  The broader question remains though, is there a good way to select all values of a given dtype?

Comment: @DoctorJ "is there a good way to select all values of a given dtype?" I don't think this is the appropriate question to ask given your problem (see [XY problems and what they mean](http://xyproblem.info)). There are ways of selecting columns that share a common dtype but no real solid way for rows because mixing types in columns is generally not a recommended practice. Hope that helps.

Comment: Re: "Is it documented anywhere that most .str functions return NaN for non-string values?" See [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#working-with-text-data) where it is mentioned: "Perhaps most importantly, these methods exclude missing/NA values automatically"

Comment: That's fair, and thank you.  I agree mixed dtypes are a bad idea; I was hoping there was a more generic method of dealing with them when you have to, something I could abstract from my particular problem this week to learn and take forward for next time.  :)